# Linker issue: undefined reference

Tags: c++, linker

I have a problem with the linker when I build my current project.

The error it comes up with is as follows:

```
libmiinddynamic.so: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& SparseImplementationLib::operator<< <double, double, SparseImplementationLib::DefaultPtr<double, double> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, SparseImplementationLib::AbstractSparseNode<double, double, SparseImplementationLib::DefaultPtr<double, double> > const&)'
```

This is slightly strange, as as far as I'm aware this method is declared in a file that is definitely being compiled:

```
namespace SparseImplementationLib {
        template <ActivityType,WeightType,ptr_type = 
DefaultPtr<ActivityType,WeightType> > class AbstractSparseNode;
    // A whole bunch of other methods
```

```
//! All derived classes from AbstractSparseNode can use operator<<
template <class ActivityType, class WeightType, class ptr_type>
ostream& operator<<
(
    ostream& s, 
    const AbstractSparseNode<ActivityType,WeightType>& node)
{
    node.ToStream(s);
    return s;
}
```

}

Why this error might pop up?

N.B. This is compiled using MPICXX on Fedora, and I'm using CCMAKE.

EDIT Ok, using nm I've found the following:

```
std::ostream& SparseImplementationLib::operator<< <double, double, SparseImplementationLib::DefaultPtr<double, double> >(std::ostream&, SparseImplementationLib::AbstractSparseNode<double, double, SparseImplementationLib::DefaultPtr<double, double> > const&)
```

when it wants this instead:

```
std::basic_ostream >& SparseImplementationLib::operator<< <double, double, SparseImplementationLib::DefaultPtr<double, double> >(std::basic_ostream >&, SparseImplementationLib::AbstractSparseNode<double, double, SparseImplementationLib::DefaultPtr<double, double> > const&)
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix this, cus operator<< only takes 2 arguments.

(The random \s before all the _s is to try and escape them, stackoverflow is being a little temperamental today and won't do it (otherwise we get lovely italics randomly in my code))

Comment: what complier and compilation line did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you nm the object which is generated by above shown code, to see that the 
signature is indeed what you expect.

Comment: In all honesty there's so many things generated by nm I'm currently very confused. The function is present in libmiindsparseimplementation.so though, which is correct afaik?

Comment: It may be a .lib order issue as someone else noted.
just give all your libraries twice (-:
or do the painful lorder+tsort magic.

Comment: Ok, using nm I seem to not have the exact function it asked for, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to parse (reformat) that line so I can read it...

```
libmiinddynamic.so: undefined reference to:
ostream & SparseImplementationLib::operator<<
   < double, double, SparseImplementationLib::DefaultPtr<double, double> >
(
   ostream &,
  SparseImplementationLib::AbstractSparseNode<
     double, double, SparseImplementationLib::DefaultPtr<double, double> > const
)
```

If I read that right, then:

- *class ActivityType* is a *double*.
- *class WeightType* is a *double*.
- *class ptr_type* is a *SparseImplementationLib::DefaultPtr<double, double>*

And somehow the second argument 
***const AbstractSparseNode<ActivityType,WeightType>&***, 
e.g ***const AbstractSparseNode<double,double>&***
  has become a:

```
  SparseImplementationLib::AbstractSparseNode<
     double,
     double,
     SparseImplementationLib::DefaultPtr<double, double>
       > const &
```

**The template argument counts don't match up.**  You've defined the second (templated) argument with 2 templated parameters and your error message indicates 3 templated parameters.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The AbstractSparseNode has a third defaulted template argument. (It defaults to . . . DefaultPtr<ActivityType,WeightType> =)